# Removing a zombie process

Tags: linux, process, signals, zombie-process

I have a use case where I have a process which is `parent` process and it spawns various `child` processes which monitors an `ssh` connection each. This `parent` process should run endlessly as a part of a service. But, when one of these `ssh` connection is closed, then that `child` process becomes a `zombie` process. This way there are many `zombie`  processes being created each time a `ssh` connection is closed.

I want to keep the number of `zombie` processes as minimal as possible. As far as I know, `SIGTERM` or `SIGKILL` does remove a `zombie` process. Since the `parent` process runs endlessly the `zombie` process cannot be removed by waiting for the `parent` to terminate.

Is there any way to remove the zombie process? Or something that I have understood wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C programming, You can use the waitpid system call in parent process.

In linux command line or shell script, you can use the wait command to remove the zombies.

waitpid manpage,

The  waitpid()  system  call suspends execution of the calling process until  a child specified by pid argument has changed state.  By default, waitpid() waits only for terminated children, but this behavior is modifiable via  the  options  arguments.

Syntax:-

```
pid_t waitpid(pid_t pid, int *status, int options);
```

If you don't want to pause the parent, then you have use the bellow system calling to clear the zombie process.

```
int status;
waitpid(0, &status, WNOHANG);
```

When the parent process does receives the child exit status, then only the zombie process is created. So, using the waitpid with WNOHANG option you can receive the child exit staus, If WNOHANG option is provided it will not block the parent. Is there any child is exited it store the exit status in the status variable, and return. Otherwise it will not wait, it simply return.

Try the [waitpid](http://linux.die.net/man/2/waitpid) man page to read about the waitpid system call.

Comment: I am using python. I tried the same. Instead of the `join()`, I replaced it with `os.waitpid(pid, os.WNOHANG)`. Still `zombie` processes are being created. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Did you check the return value of the waitpid ?

Comment: I don't know in python. But I think we have to  pass any argument to the os.waitpid to get the exist status ?

Comment: @nidHi If you passed the pid to the os.waitpid, then then it clears only that one zombie process. Instead of giving pid, give the 0 in os.waitpid. I think it will work.

Comment: Yes... I had made an error code wise... It's working with `waitpid()` now... Thank you for the help..!